# Swift Protocol Extension - Can't Access Func

Tags: swift, protocols

If I have a series of protocols like so:

```
    protocol Customer {

    var name:String { get set }
    var age: Int { get set }
    var startDate:Date { get set }
    var meals:Array<String> { get set }
    var market:Int { get set }

}

protocol Vegan:Customer {

}

protocol Vegetarian:Customer {

}

protocol Paleo:Customer {


}
```

and extension like so:

```
    extension Customer where Self:Vegan, Self:Vegetarian {

    func getMeals() -> Array<String> {
        return ["VeganMeal1", "VeganMeal2", "VeganMeal3", "VeganMeal4"]
    }
}

extension Customer where Self:Vegetarian {

    func getMeals() -> Array<String> {
        return ["VegetarianMeal1", "VegetarianMeal2", "VegetarianMeal3", "VegetarianMeal4"]
    }
}

extension Customer where Self:Paleo {

    func getMeals() -> Array<String> {
        return ["PaleoMeal1", "PaleoMeal2", "PaleoMeal3", "PaleoMeal4"]
    }
}
```

and this struct

```
    struct aCustomer:Customer, Vegan {

    var name:String
    var age: Int
    var startDate:Date
    var meals:Array<String>
    var market:Int

}
```

when I create a new object based on that struct

```
var newCustomer = aCustomer(name:"William", age:40, startDate:Date(), meals:[], market:1)
```

how come I can't access the getMeals function in the extensions? I get an error stating getMeals is an ambiguous reference.

[image]

Comment: Because of your first where clause ‘where Self:Vegan, Self:Vegetarian’ please look at the code

Comment: ah, thanks, do you do an or with || like in a conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension Customer where Self:Vegan, Self:Vegetarian {
```

extends Customer in the case where the adopter or Customer also both adopts Vegan and Vegetarian. Your `aCustomer` (a struct type starting with a small letter?? the horror, the horror) does not do that, so the extension doesn't apply to it.

If the goal is to inject the same code *either* when the adopter adopts Vegan *or* when the adopter adopts Vegetarian, use two extensions, or, if you don't like the repetition, have them both adopt some "higher" protocol that is extended with the desired code to be injected.

Comment: Thank heavens! :)))

Comment: How do you do Vegan OR Vegetarian?

Comment: I've already given an answer to that... On the whole, though, I'd say watch out for trying to use protocol "inheritance" like class inheritance. They are not the same thing. I'm starting to think what you really need here is a hierarchy of classes...

Comment: Actually your answer brought back the ambiguous error for getMeals(). In your answer you said both adopts Vegan **and** Vegetarian, I was looking for something where it adopts Vegan or Vegetarian, or maybe I am misunderstanding you. I'm just fiddling with some thoughts for an upcoming project so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Never mind, I see where you answered it. It's Sunday, I'm using that as my excuse.